# How to update ubuntu terminal?3

Tags: updates

When I run the command `apt-get update`.Error occurred

```
root@ubuntu:~# apt-get update


E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am unable to solve this problem.could anyone help me?

Comment: Is that the entire error message?

Comment: put the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` in your question

Answer (score 0):

Find out what's causing the error. There must be some broken PPAa. To see these PPAs when you run `sudo apt-get update`, look at the lines that say

> W: Failed to fetch: 'url of ppa'

Now go to Software & Updates > Other Software and remove the conflicting PPAs.

If the error is causing because of the presence of unsupported packages, remove that package in the sources.lst. TO do this type:

> sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

search for the missing package (http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz in this case) and remove the line containing this entry.

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-security/restricted/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

Comment: go to Software & Updates > Other Software and see if this is listed. Remove this from the list.

Comment: What I do remove.