# err: unable to locate package package:i386

Tags: error-handling

When i install 32-bit libraries through command

```
sudo apt-get install 32-bit
```

libraries.Error occurred unable to locate package.

Please give me solution of this error.

Comment: @karel The OP didn't state the Version... The problem in the package name not in supported version or not

Comment: This is the third `E: unable to locate` question by Jeetu Donderiya and I'm going to keep on flagging them to wear him out until he upgrades his system or stops repeating the same question over and over again. However is upvoting so much crap is giving him a reason to keep on doing the same thing over and over.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to update ubuntu terminal?3](http://askubuntu.com/questions/615226/how-to-update-ubuntu-terminal3). possible duplicate of [How do I install build-essential?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/615161/how-do-i-install-build-essential). This is what I'm talking about in the preceding comment.

Comment: @NewUSer I'll explain my thought processes in more detail. Jeetu had 10.10. Your ia32-libs package which in your answer you think he's referring to is only available in 12.04. But if Jeetu has upgraded his OS, why wouldn't he have upgraded it to 14.04 instead of 12.04? So your answer makes sense only under the two conditions that Jeetu upgraded to 12.04 and that by 32-bit or 32-bit libraries or whatever unclear thing he wrote he was referring to ia32-libs.

Comment: @karel i also answered for versions 13.10 and above

Comment: @NewUSer You haven't convinced me by suggesting that I haven't read your answer (which of course I did, since we're obviously discussing your answer too) and that this question is anything else but bait.

Comment: @karel Sry if you feel like that I don't mean that for you....

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in

```
sudo apt-get install 32-bit
```

There is no package called 32-bit for that you got this error

you should use the following

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

**PS** if you use Ubuntu 13.10 or higher, you'll need install these packages instead:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
```